# Swift: Implicit Return Not Compiling?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was checking out the Swift documentation on implicit returns. Consider this function from the docs:

```
func greeting(for person: String) -> String {
    "Hello, " + person + "!"
}
```

When I copy and paste it into xCode I get an error: "Missing return in a function expected to return 'String' "

My swift version is set to 5.0 in build settings.

Honestly don't know if I am missing something obvious here, or if there is a problem with my other xCode build settings? Ideas?

Comment: Implicit return in functions is not supported until Swift 5.1 (Xcode 11).

Comment: ... and [here is the proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md) for reference

Comment: Thought that might be it - thank you !

Comment: @Alladinian You should cook that up as an answer. You get internet points, and the question can be marked as solved :)

Comment: @Alexander The reason I settled with a comment is because Sulthan (first time I notice that only one mention is allowed btw :/ ) was the first to comment on this. Credit where credit is due...