# Is "Return" keyword mandatory for swift functions with return value

Tags: swift

The following code shows an implementation for a function with a return value.

```
func isValid() -> Bool {
    self.txtComment.text.isEmpty
}
```

As you may noticed the return keyword not used. even-though, there is no syntax error!

**Is this logically correct? or there will be logical problems?**

Comment: It's made like that in swift version 5.something

Comment: so for 1 liners this is valid?

Comment: Do you know of a reference doc you can add in an answer?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0255-implicit-returns-from-single-expression-functions/22544

Comment: why would anyone downvote this question :)

Comment: I vote down the questions that I do not think add to the internet. People already put good effort into making this clear. No reason to waste time asking and answering when it’s here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: @Jessy Is that a Stack Overflow guide line? The vast majority of questions on stack overflow would be found in a documentation somewhere!

Comment: @hasan "Is this logically correct? or there will be a logical problems?" As others has already mentioned Swift 5.1 it is allowed to omit the return keyword when there is a single expression. Note that text is optional `self.txtComment.text?.isEmpty == true` but if it is an `UITextField` its default value is an empty String, therefore you can force unwrap it `self.txtComment.text!.isEmpty` or use UIKeyInput hasText property. You can also implement it as a computed property considering that it signature has no parameters `var isValid: Bool { txtComment.hasText }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for the explanation. I meant for the non-existence of the return keyword. I used "logical" word here because there was no syntax error. Ty for the effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812483/swift-implicit-return-not-compiling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382404/did-xcode-11-start-ignoring-missing-return-statement-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [did Xcode 11 start ignoring missing 'return' statement errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382404/did-xcode-11-start-ignoring-missing-return-statement-errors)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called [Functions With an Implicit Return](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID607):

> If the entire body of the function is **a single expression**, the function *implicitly* returns that expression.

Added in swift 5.1. You can check [the proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is logically correct as from swift 5.1. You do not need to explicitly type the return keyword anymore if your function only has **one** line of code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Opaque types. They just happened to be introduced at the same time.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the clarification! I confused the two of them while reading the 5.1 changes.

Answer (score 0):

Swift lets us skip using the return keyword when we have only one expression in our function. So, these two functions do the same thing:

```
func doSomething() -> Int {
    return 5 + 5
}

func doSomethingMore() -> Int {
    5 + 5
}
```

Well, the ternary operator works here too. For instance:

```
func sayHello(to name: String) -> String {
    if name == "Hasan" {
        return "Hey Smart!"
    } else {
        return "Hello, \(name)"
    }
}
```

we could use the ternary operator like this:

```
func sayHello(to name: String) -> String {
    name == "Hasan" ? "Hey Smart!" : "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

So, when that function runs it effectively boils down to this:

```
func greet(name: String) -> String {
    "Hey Smart!"
}
```

reference:
[hackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-is-the-return-keyword-not-needed-in-a-swift-function)
[swift-evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md)